# Can't click links or highlight text

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

I have been struggling with this for a couple days and have finally conceded to ask for help. I've tried answers to similar questions, but they haven't fixed the problem.

I can't highlight text or click links on [lilliannordica.com/lily-of-the-north](http://www.lilliannordica.com/lily-of-the-north) or any other pages on this site except the home page. I know something must be in front, but after staring at this for hours and hours, I still don't see it.

There are several things on this website I did for the first time, so I'm guessing I messed one of them up. I don't even know what css to include in this, so here's all of it.

```
body{
    background: #352144;
    font-family:  Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

li {
    font-size: 18px;
}

a:link {
    color:#fd027a;
}

a:hover {
    color:#dcd111;
}

a:visited {
    color:#53b111;
}


.brand-image {
    background: #352144;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#lillian-sig {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px;
}


.navbar-default {
  background-color: #c0a5b4;
  border-color: #b899aa;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .125em;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #f8ece0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f8ece0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #c0a5b4;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #352144;
  background-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
  background-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #352144;
  background-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #352144;
  background-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #352144;
  background-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #b899aa;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #352144;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: none;
}



/* Page headers */

.header-box {
    background-color: #352144;
}


.header-image {
    width: 99.5%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}



#lillian-head {
    color: #352144;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

#lillian-head h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #352144;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 650%;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 8%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#lillian-subhead {
    position: absolute;
    color: #352144;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 275%;
    letter-spacing: .075em;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 8%;

}





#museum-head {
    color: #352144;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

#museum-head h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #352144;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 650%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    right: 45%; 
}


#table {
    display: none;
}

#tour-small {
    display: none;
}

#tour-two-small {
    display: none;
}



#home-head {
    color: #f8ece0;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
}



#home-head h1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #f8ece0;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 400%;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    top: 5%;
    left: 55%;
    right: 2%;
}

#home-subhead {
    position: absolute;
    color: #f8ece0;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 160%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 55%;
    right: 2%;

}

#lowerhome {
    background: #71637c;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px;
}

#lowerhome img {
    position: relative; 
}

.smaller-home-text {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 175%;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #F8ECE0;
}

.larger-home-text {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 345%;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    color: #F8ECE0;
}

#memorial-home-text {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 300%;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #F8ECE0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 63%;
    right: .001em;  
}

#memorial-smaller-text {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 225%;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
    color: #F8ECE0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 77%;
    right: .001em;
}

#contact-home-text {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 340%;
    letter-spacing: .01em;
    color: #F8ECE0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 37%;
    right: .001em;
}

#lillianhomelink p.smaller-home-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 72%;
    right: .001em;  
}

#lillianhomelink p.larger-home-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 75%;
    right: .001em;  
}

#museumhomelink p.smaller-home-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 55%;
    right: .001em;
}

#museumhomelink p.larger-home-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 60%;
    right: .001em;
}

#memorialhomelink p.smaller-home-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 53%;
    right: .001em;
}

#linkshomelink p.larger-home-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 37%;
    right: .001em;
}



.float-left {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}



.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.content-wrapper {  
  background: #fbf5ef;
  padding: 150px 15px 50px;
  margin-top: -250px;
}

.content {
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #352144;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.content a {
    z-index: 1;
}

.template-h1 {
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-size: 36px;
}

h2, h3, .subheading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

h4 .subheading {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}


img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.row.no-gutters {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
}
.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
}

figure {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#wagnerian h2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#last{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.books {
    font-weight: 600;
}

#museum h2 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}


#museum .first {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#museum {
    margin-top: 75px;
}


#footer {
  border-top: 10px solid #c0a5b4;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f9efe6;
  color: #352144;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

footer {
  height: 225px;
  clear: both;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footer img {
    padding: 20px 15px 10px;
}

#footer a {
  color: #352144;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.border-right {
      border-right: 2px solid #352144;
}

#footer ul li a {
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footernav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#footernav li {
        float: left;
}

#mission {
    font-size: 95%;
    padding: 30px 25px 15px;
}


#subfooter {
    background: #2b1b37;
    color: #f8ece0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#subfooter a {
    text-decoration: none;
}



/* @medias in order from smallest to largest */



@media (max-width:399px){
#lillian-head h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#lillian-subhead {
    font-size: 110%;
    letter-spacing: .075em;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: 10%;
}


#museum-head h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}



#home-head {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#home-head h1 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 58%;
    right: 4%;
}

#home-subhead {
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 140%;  
    left: 58%;
    right: 4%;
    top: 20%;
}

#lowerhome {
    background: #fbf5ef;
    padding: 20px 50px 15px;
}



.page-top h1 {
    font-size: 275%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 8%;
}

#association-content {
    padding-top: 175px; 
    padding-left: 30px;
}



#lily-page-top h1 {
    font-size: 225%;
    left: 4%
}

#lily-subhead {
    font-size: 125%;
    line-height: 140%;
    left: 4%;
    top: 350%
}

#lily-content {
    padding-top: 175px;
}



#scholarship-page-top h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    bottom: -350%;
    left: 7%;
    right: 15%
}

#scholarship-subhead {
    font-size: 125%;
    top: 450%;
    left: 8%;
}

#scholarship-content {
    padding-top: 225px;
}

.smaller-home-text {
    font-size: 125%;
}

.larger-home-text {
    font-size: 275%;
}

#contact-home-text {
    font-size: 275%;
}

#memorial-home-text {
    font-size: 250%;
}

#memorial-smaller-text {
    font-size: 140%;
}

}

@media (min-width:400px) and (max-width:649px){
#lillian-head h1 {
    font-size: 325%;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#lillian-subhead {
    font-size: 127%;
    letter-spacing: .075em;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 25%;
}


#museum-head h1 {
    font-size: 300%;
    bottom: 35%;
    left: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}




#home-head {
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

#home-head h1 {
    font-size: 163%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 4%;  
    top: -1%;
}

#home-subhead {
    font-size: 95%; 
    left: 50%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 15%;
}


.page-top h1 {
    font-size: 260%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 2%;
}



#lily-page-top h1 {
    font-size: 300%;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    left: 4%;
}

#lily-subhead {
    font-size: 125%;
    line-height: 140%;
    left: 4%;
    top: 350%;
}

#lily-content {
    padding-top: 165px;
}


#scholarship-page-top h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    bottom: -190%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 15%
}

#scholarship-subhead {
    font-size: 150%;
    top: 275%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 10%;
}

#scholarship-content {
    padding-top: 200px;
}

.smaller-home-text {
    font-size: 175%;
}

.larger-home-text {
    font-size: 350%;
}

#contact-home-text {
    font-size: 350%;
}

#memorial-home-text {
    font-size: 300%;
    top: 62%
}

#memorial-smaller-text {
    font-size: 175%;
    top: 73%;
}
}


@media (max-width:649px){
 .navbar-default {
  background-color: #352144;
  border-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #352144;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #fbf5ef;
  background-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
    height:2px;
  background-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fbf5ef;
  background-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #fbf5ef;
  background-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #493756;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #fbf5ef;
}

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #fbf5ef;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fbf5ef;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fbf5ef;
    background-color: #493756;
  }



  .navbar-toggle {
      color: #F8ECE0;
}
    .brand-image {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        display: inline-flex;
        background-image: url(../../images/small_signature.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: auto 50px;
        padding-right: 200px;
        padding-top: 2px;
    }

.header-image {
    width: 100%
    }   

.border-right {
      border-right: 0px;
      border-bottom: 0px;
      padding: 10px 0px;
}

#lastnav {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

#subfooter {
    font-size: 90%;
}

.duo {
    padding-top: 30px;  
}

#lily-content img {
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
}

}



@media (min-width:650px) and (max-width:959px) {
#lillian-head h1 {
    font-size: 400%;
    bottom: 48%;
    left: 8%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#lillian-subhead {
    font-size: 150%;
    letter-spacing: .075em;
    left: 8%;
    bottom: 37%;
}

#columbia {
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#sufferage {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#museum-head h1 {
    font-size: 400%;
    bottom: 48%;
    left: 8%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}



#tour {
    display: none;
}

#tour-small {
    display: block;
}

#tour-two {
    display: none;
}

#tour-two-small {
    display: block;
}

#home-head h1 {
    font-size: 258%;
    left: 55%;
    top: 5%;
}

#home-subhead {
    font-size: 125%;
    left: 55%;
    right: 5%;
    top: 20%;
}   

.page-top h1 {
    top: 10%;
    left: 1%;
}

#association-content {
    padding-top: 135px; 
}

#lily-page-top h1 {
    top: 5%;
    left: 3%;
}

#lily-subhead {
    top: 260%;
    left: 3%;
}

#lily-content {
    padding-top: 170px;
}

#scholarship-page-top h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: 3%;
    right: 2%
}

#scholarship-subhead {
    font-size: 150%;
    top: 140%;
    left: 3%;
}

#scholarship-content {
    padding-top: 125px;
}



.smaller-home-text {
    font-size: 100%;
}

.larger-home-text {
    font-size: 200%;
}

#contact-home-text {
    font-size: 200%;
    top: 50%;
}

#memorial-home-text {
    font-size: 175%;
}

#memorial-smaller-text {
    font-size: 125%;
}

#linkshomelink {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#contacthomelink {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#linkshomelink p.larger-home-text {
    top: 50%;
}

#table {
    display: block;
}

.line {
    display: inline;
}



}



@media (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1199px) {
#lillian-head h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
    bottom: 48%;
    left: 10%;
}

#lillian-subhead {
    font-size: 175%;
    bottom: 37%;
    left: 10%;
}

#columbia {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#sufferage {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#museum-head h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
    bottom: 48%;
    left: 10%;

}



#home-head h1 {
    font-size: 365%;
    left: 57%;
    top: 5%;
}

#home-subhead {
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    left: 58%;      
}

.page-top h1 {
    top: 25%;
    left: 9.25%;
}

#lily-page-top h1 {
    top: 10%;
    left: 9.5%;
}

#lily-subhead {
    top: 175%;
    left: 10%;
}

#lily-content {
    padding-top: 130px;
}

#scholarship-page-top h1 {
    font-size: 350%;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: 9%;
    right: 5%
}

#scholarship-subhead {
    font-size: 150%;
    top: 150%;
    left: 10%;
}

#scholarship-content {
    padding-top: 150px;
}

.smaller-home-text {
    font-size: 170%;
}

.larger-home-text {
    font-size: 335%;
}

#contact-home-text {
    font-size: 335%;
    top: 43%;
}

#memorial-home-text {
    font-size: 290%;
}

#memorial-smaller-text {
    font-size: 200%;
}

#contacthomelink {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#linkshomelink {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#linkshomelink p.larger-home-text{
    top: 43%;
}

}

@media (max-width:1199px) {
.header-image {
    width: 100%;
}

        #full {
        display: none;
        }

    #half {
        display: block;
        margin-left: -8px;
    }

    #wagnerian {
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    .wagnerian-p {
        margin-left: -8px;
    }

}

@media (min-width:1200px) {


#contacthomelink {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
#linkshomelink{
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#linkshomelink p.larger-home-text {
    top: 43%;
}
#contact-home-text {
    top: 43%;
}

#columbia {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#sufferage {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
}

@media (min-width:1334px) {
        #full {
        display: none;
        }

    #half {
        display: block;
        margin-left: -8px;
    }

    #wagnerian {
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    .wagnerian-p {
        margin-left: -8px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) and (max-width:1333px) {
    #full {
        display: inline;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    #half {
        display: none;
    }

    #wagnerian {
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    .wagnerian-p {
        margin-left: -8px;
    }
}


@media (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1333px) {
#wagnerian {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

    #wagnerian h2 {
    margin-top: -30px;
}


#last{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}   
}
```

Comment: While you have my sympathy, the last paragraph of your question doesn't add anything relevant to your question, so I'd recommend removing it (someone likely will remove it for you anyway). When in doubt, try to follow the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within your actual site, you need to remove `z-index: -1` from `.content-wrapper`. That is dropping the entire content below the clickable area, which is why you can't highlight text or click links.